# Creating a list of random numbers shorter than specified 'count' between [0,1) greater than specified 'cutoff'

Tags: python, arcgis, arcpy

I am just starting in Python (though have coding experience in other languages) and am working on this assignment for a class in ArcGIS pro. We have been tasked with using the random module to generate a list of random numbers between 0 and 1 with a few different 'cutoffs' (shown here 0.7) and 'counts' shown here 5.

I have tried a few different ways of approaching this problem including using nested loops (shown below, different count and cutoff) but came out with a list too long. I am now trying to approach the problem using only a while loop after some guidance from my professor, yet my list remains... empty? Any help is appreciated.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bNdX.png)

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEydA.png)

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide your code as text and not as image.

Comment: `random.uniform(0.7,1.0)` does a much better job in this case.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the right idea, just some bugs in your code. The first one, your `x` is just counting from `0` to `count` and that's what you are appending to your list of numbers rather than the `random.random()` output. Also, you didn't assign any value to your `random.random()` output either.

The second example is much closer to what you're looking for, but you are missing a colon after the `if` statement and the `numbers.append(x)` should be indented.

```
import random
seed = 37
cutoff = 0.4
count = 8

random.seed(seed)

numbers = []
while len(numbers) < count:
    x = random.random()
    if x > cutoff:
        numbers.append(x)
        
print(numbers)
```

Answer (score 0):

Consistent with the suggestion by @Tim to use `random.uniform()`, here is a complete solution that builds on his guidance:

```
import random

count, cutoff, seed = 10, 0.4, 37

random.seed(seed)

numbers = [
    random.uniform(cutoff, 1.0)
    for _ in range(count)
]
print(numbers)
```

Output:

```
[0.8092027363527867, 0.45496156484773836, 0.7706898093168415, 0.9051519427305738, 0.9007301731456538, 0.7090106354748096, 0.778622779177406, 0.6215379004377511, 0.7168111732115348, 0.46471400998163914]
```